# YouTube player is not working in iOS on certain videoid

Tags: ios, youtube-api

YouTube Helper Library in iOS does not working on certain videoId-'ozUdQJxvQCk'.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

I followed the guide.
Playing well on other platforms(android, mweb, and in youtube)

[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"ozUdQJxvQCk"];

When the video is loaded and the play button is pressed, the following logs are displayed.

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have the same exact issue and I cannot figure it out...

Comment: @Carey Richardson, I figured it out in other post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55788562/some-youtube-videos-do-not-play-in-apps-with-the-ytplayer-sdk