# Some YouTube videos do not play, in apps with the ytplayer SDK

Tags: ios, youtube-api, ytplayer

We're testing our app with the ytplayer SDK provided by YouTube.
Please refer to the link below.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper?hl=ko

The problem is, when I play some videos I can not play only in the app. This video plays very well on Youtube apps, mobile webs (Safari apps) and desktop browsers. (videoId:ozUdQJxvQCk)

I tried it in the SDK sample app on YouTube, but the problem was the same. In other words, it's not just my app's issue.

The error code returned from the SDK looks like this:
"Decoding failed with error code -1"

If anyone knows how to solve it, please answer it.

==

Attach the sample app code. Of the two videos, the above is normal and the one below is the problematic one.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, (self.view.frame.size.height - self.view.frame.size.width) / 2, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width);
    YTPlayerView *yt = [[YTPlayerView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [self.view addSubview:yt];

    // [yt loadWithVideoId:@"yv90i_afcPI"];  // it's ok
    [yt loadWithVideoId:@"ozUdQJxvQCk"];  // video unavailable
}
```

Comment: share your tried code ? and how you use SDK pod or manually ?

Comment: @PratikPrajapati Thanks for the comment. I added the source code to the body. Unfortunately, pod or manual issues are the same.

Comment: try this code. `youTubePlayer.load(withVideoId: NYT_Data.video_id, playerVars: ["playsinline" : 1,"showinfo":0,"autoplay":1,"origin" : "https://www.youtube.com","controls" : 0,"enablejsapi": 1,"rel": 0,"iv_load_policy": 3,"cc_load_policy":1]` convert it in objC

Comment: @PratikPrajapati OH MY GOD you saved my time! Do you work on YouTube? How do you know? I added "origin" and "enablejsapi" in your comments and it plays very well. Thank you so much!

Comment: i used this SDK in one of my project and some youtube video required `origin` for playing.

Comment: @PratikPrajapati that's interesting. Anyway, I am glad that the problem has been solved. Because today is the day I update my app. I am so grateful to you that I do not know how to repay you. Thanks for answering my first question!